# Can I create a link from within my webview browser that will call a specific function

Tags: ios, webview

We are using the native geolocation data in the address string we use when we create a webview component (eg http://example.com?long=36.333&latt=-143.222). The reason we are doing this is that we want to check location but don't want to use the browser location facility which pops up an alert each day asking if we can use your location.

Ideally I want to be able to create a new webview component (with new location data) in response to a click on a link within the webview component.  I know we can call the app from a link (eg myappname://) but can I add parameters to this call to trigger certain events such as a function that we reload the webview component?

If it cant be done from a link within the html, I assume I will have to place a native button on the page and call it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do. First of all, set link like http://example.com?#SetCustomLocation in your HTML content.

Set WebView Delegate method like bellow :

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType
{
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked )
    {
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [inRequest URL]];
        if([url hasSuffix:@"#SetCustomLocation"])
        {
            NSString *strURL = @"http://example.com?long=36.333&latt=-143.222"; //Set Custom URL with Lat/long Whatever you need
            NSURL *cURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[strURL tringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:cURL];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Regards.